# Issue in removing user to a mailbox Exchange Server 2010 (set-mailbox remove)

Tags: powershell

I tried with many options like checking add/remove permissions users to the others mailbox users, but its not working.

I executed below command in my Exchange Management Shell :

```
Set-Mailbox 'mailboxname' –GrantSendOnbehalfto @{ Remove="john@ncbb.com","kim@fghgh.com" }

error: the command completed successfully but no settings of 'mailboxname' have been modified.
```

Comment: Can you try with an email address ? `Set-Mailbox 'mailboxname' –GrantSendOnbehalfto 'john@domain.com'` or `Set-Mailbox 'mailboxname' –GrantSendOnbehalfto @{ Add="john@domain.com","kim@domain.com" }`

Comment: i tried with email address but its same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you have listed isn't really an error, it's more of a warning. It's not telling you that it can't do something, it's just saying the parameters you provided don't exist.

I recently wrote a script that had the same issue, and I just had to mess around with it. Mine ended up needing the sAMAccountname instead of email or surname/givenname. In other words, instead of using 'test.account@abc.com', it wanted TAccount which was the username.

It may help to dig into your AD, or install an LDAP browser or AD Explorer to see what your organization names things. When I did this, I found out that half of the things I was calling in my scripts by name was *completely* incorrect just because of the naming convention.